# All meshes no longer visible after selecting certain animation

Tags: modeling, animation

In the dope sheet, I found a new animation which I did not create. When I clicked on it, immediately all my meshes disappeared and I am not sure how to make them reappear.

Currently using Godot Game Tools and Animations from mixamo, and I was editing the individual mixamo animations when this happened

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CsQx1G9USeA1Ti1mPVEAr2htko2OPWju/view?usp=sharing

Hopefully its not something trivial

Comment: Try pressing ctrl + z until you see your mesh

Comment: I did but I ran out of presses :(